# How would wings on the head work? What muscle structure would they need and how flexible could they be?

Tags: anatomy

I've seen many creatures that others have made with wings instead of ears, and the like. And I've always wondered how that would work from an anatomy standpoint?

- How would they connect to the head?
- What would the muscles be like?
- How flexible could they be? (as flexible as normal wings? Able to point in front of and behind the head? / above and below? )
- Would there be an affect on the other muscles of the face?

They don't have to have the same strength as wings used for flight, since they'd be for social uses. cartilage can be used etc.

Comment: Fennecs have fairly large ears for their size, though they are not wing-shaped. Some breeds of dogs have very large, floppy ears.

Comment: They'd most likely be modified ears, and I doubt they'd have bones in them. Regarding muscles, bat's have 20 muscles specifically directed to moving their ears, so we could have something similar here for the "flapping" motion we so commonly see. Maybe they'd work as an owls' ear tufts, serving both for hearing and for demonstrating mood and emotions. They'd likely cause problems for the jaw muscles,though, especially the temporalis, since they're so close to them (assuming a human-shaped skull) .

Comment: As long as you put the brain somewhere else, no problem. But making sure you have blood flow to both brain and wings, through the neck? Not likely.

Comment: Are you ruling out insect wings? They would seem to bypass most or all concerns raised so far.

Comment: One major issue is that your neck would need to support the weight of your entire body on a regular basis.

Comment: Could you specify a weight range? Size is probably the most important factor to consider when testing the plausibility of flight.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Small muscles, not gonna work. It would be as flexibile as ears, unless some bone structure is developed.

To make it work the ear must be turned into a full limb or a membrane of skin that runs from the ears down all the way to the legs, like a jumpsuit.

Stand up, go in front a mirror, flex your bicep.... You need 6 times that to fly.

Comment: Could you add a caption explaining what your figure is depicting?